# How do you use potassium bicarbonate to control powdery mildew?

Tags: fungus, organic, pesticide

[This post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/why-do-my-tomato-leaves-look-powdery/1753#1753) describes using potassium bicarbonate to control powdery mildew, but doesn't give any more info.

So I'm looking for the following:

Efficacy?
Mixing rate?
Application rate?
Application frequency?

And finally, are there different types of potassium bicarbonate and, if so, can they all be used for this purpose?

Comment: I don't use bicarb for this, its a hell of a lot easier to use cow's milk - 1 part cow's milk to 9 parts water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it did not work for powdery mildew on lupins or Monarda. Your mileage may vary:

- add one tablespoon potassium bicarbonate to a quart of water
- consider adding a bit of vegetable oil as a "sticker"
- pour in to a hand powered sprayer
- agitate vigorously to get a suspension
- spray, agitate, repeat